# Open source hotel booking system

Tags: open-source, reservation

I am searching for an open source hotel booking system, preferably written in Java.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations Stack Exchange! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Basically just need more details on what features your require.

Comment: So, you run a hotel, and you want to allow clients to book online, right? Do you already have a website? If yes, what language is it written in, PHP, JSF, JSP? Do you need to connect with a third-party commercial website for money transactions? If yes which one?

Comment: Keep an eye on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17550/university-rooms-reservations-software-foss

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will add system written in Java, but I'd like to show you there are such a systems available as plugins/extensions of popular CMS (content management system) platforms. They are not necessarily free, but they are open source (so you get source code after purchase)

- CMS Joomla! - [search](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=booking) - example found: [jomres](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/booking-a-reservations/booking/335?qh=YTo2OntpOjA7czo3OiJib29raW5nIjtpOjE7czo0OiJib29rIjtpOjI7czo4OiJib29raW5ncyI7aTozO3M6NToiYm9va3MiO2k6NDtzOjY6ImJvb2tlZCI7aTo1O3M6NjoiYm9vaydzIjt9)
- CMS Wordpress - [search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=booking) - example found: [Booking System (Booking Calendar)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/booking-system/)

Hopefully this shows you the idea.