# University rooms reservations software (FOSS)

Tags: open-source, reservation

I need a FOSS software to handle university rooms reservations. University rooms can have different maximum people amount.
I have found some, but I need others, to be able to do a bigger comparison

- http://italc.sourceforge.net
- http://mrbs.sourceforge.net

The software can be both an offline and online software (but I would prefer offline).
OS: Linux and/or Windows 7

Comment: Why is it relevant that the rooms can have different maximum amounts of people?  Is that just part of the description of the room that is available, or should the software automatically match the rooms based on how many people are attending different events, adjusted in real-time?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard the software should automatically match the rooms based on how many people are attending different events

Comment: keep an eye on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10248/open-source-hotel-booking-system

Comment: Can you give us some more detail about which features you would like to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some years ago, we installed [Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If your university happens to be using G Suite (a.k.a. Google Apps), it now has support for building and room management built-in to Google Calendar:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1686462?hl=en